# How to use getEventListeners in Chrome Dev Tool?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I tried to trace back which function hooked into a click event of `.someclass`. I open Chrome Dev Tool and type this

```
getEventListeners(document.querySelector('.someclass'));
```

The result is this

`Object {}`

I cannot click and open it to find out the name of the object or the source code that handle click event.

Is there a way to find out?

**UPDATE 1:**

Followed **Krasimir's** advise below. There could be only two events: `mousemove` or `mouseover`. So how do I find out the exact function handling that event for `canvas.overlay`? There are just too many to drill down into.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

1. Open the DevTools
2. Open the Elements tab and locate your element (.someclass)
3. There are four tabs per element - Styles, Properties, DOM Breakpoints and Event Listeners
4. Select Event Listeners

[image]

Comment: I added update with screenshot. There are too many drill down nodes. Which one do I pick to find out the exact function?

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to say without to see the actual page.

Comment: Even without a screenshot this answer is great!

Answer (score 16):

You are getting an empty object when calling

```
getEventListeners(document.querySelector('.someclass'));
```

probably because the listener isn't hooked up to `.someclass` element itself (direct event), but to one of it's ancestors (delegated event). There is a good explanation of this [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

You can list both delegated and direct events by calling `getEventListeners` for specified node **and** all it's ancestors. This function should do the trick:

```
getAllEventListeners = function(el) {
 var allListeners = {}, listeners;

 while(el) {
  listeners = getEventListeners(el);

  for(event in listeners) {
   allListeners[event] = allListeners[event] || [];
   allListeners[event].push({listener: listeners[event], element: el});  
  }

  el = el.parentNode;
 }

 return allListeners;
}
```

However, this will output exactly the same thing as the "Event Listeners" tab (with "Filter" option set to "All nodes") that Krasimir mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I ran and it worked but it gave me bunch of events and I don't know which one to pick :(

Comment: @HP. I don't understand what you are trying to find. If you are searching for the `click` event handler then you've got only one on the list. If you are searching for `mousemove` event over `canvas.overlay` then there is only one either.

Comment: Sorry if I caused confusion but I saw many functions under `mousemove` like `prototype: Object` or `__proto__: function Empty()` or `<function scope>` so I am not sure which one is the listener function.

Comment: I'm getting an error with `hasOwnProperty`, which is not a function in `listeners`. Should I use `event.hasOwnProperty()`? That way it doesn't fail but `allListeners` ends as an empty object, as that functions always returns `false`.

Comment: @Andrew skip the `hasOwnProperty` check (I've updated the code). For some reason in Chrome this method was removed from object returned by `getEventListeners`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Here's a simplified version of your code to get the list of nodes and their own events, so you know where each one of them comes from:
`var el = document.querySelector('.someclass');
while (el) {
 console.log(el, getEventListeners(el));
 el = el.parentNode;
}`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using jQuery to bind the events to that element.
That's why you can't see the actual handler code in the drill down menu.
Without wrapped by jQuery, the actual code should be displayed in "listenerBody" like this:

[image]